# Preload network images to avoid load times

Tags: dart, flutter

I'd like to add and remove items on top of each on the press of a button to avoid load times for network images.
My idea is to add ~5 images to a Stack on top of each other and be able to remove the top one and add another on to the back so that it can pre-load.

I did not find any documentation or answers if this is possible with the [Stack class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

I also had the idea to use a [Dismissible](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Dismissible-class.html), but there seems to be no way to change child and background on it either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have to create a stack to preload images; what you're looking for is the NetworkImage class. You could maintain a set of NetworkImage classes that you've manually loaded and pass one of those into the `Image` constructor, but I'm fairly sure that flutter actually caches the last few images you've loaded in memory automatically so that isn't even really needed (I think I heard the last 100 images or so but I could be wrong).

Unfortunately, the API isn't all that simple for it (there's a [bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3905) open about this in the flutter repo), but it's not all that difficult either.

All you need is a method somewhere like this (or just do it in a build function):

```
static void preload(BuildContext, String path) {
  final configuration = createLocalImageConfiguration(context);
  NetworkImage(path).resolve(configuration);
}
```

Call that from anywhere you have a valid build context. And TBH, you could construct the `ImageConfiguration` yourself and pass that in instead (just look at the source for `createLocalImageConfiguration` to get an idea about that).

If you want to get a bit fancier about it, instead of just making an `NetworkImage` and resolving it, you could have a class that maintains a map of preloaded `NetworkImage`s and returns them when you want.

Another thing you can do which might be enough to resolve your problem without doing anything else is setting `gaplessPlayback = true` where you construct your Image.network - that will make sure that the image doesn't switch until the next image is fully loaded.

Hope that helps =). If it doesn't actually work let me know though and I'll dig a bit deeper - I haven't done it in code myself yet.

Comment: That would probably solve my problem, I'm gonna play around with this later.
However, can you thing of a way in which I could animate a "swiping" animation with this? I would like to swipe away multiple images. As far as I understand the Dismissible only works with one background. Do you know a way in which I could stack multiple images in dismissibles?

Comment: Hmmm.. that might be a candidate for a separate question (sorry, maybe I shouldn't have changed the title but I thought this was mostly about preloading - you could change it back it you want).
In that case a stack might actually be the best answer. But realistically, you probably don't want to make a stack of dismissibles as that may not work all that well (you'd need to propagate a change upwards to delete once the dismissible dismisses).

Comment: One option could be to create a gesturedetector with a stack under it and manage transitions yourself (look at the source code for dismissible - you can probably copy parts of it to achieve this).

Another option might be to keep a list of images/urls, create a dismissible with the first image and second image as background, then once it has been dismissed notify your widget using onDismissed. Wherever you handle that you'd `setState`, remove first image/url in list, and in your build function make a new dismissible. I'm not 100% sure that would work though.

Comment: My thouhgs with this were kinda all over the place.
I needed both, the image preloading and the dismissing. Preloading works as you described and for the dismissing I'm now using a Stack with a changing state which cycles the items and some animations.
Thanks for your help

Comment: For now I don't need the swiping part of dismissible, I'm just using a simple button press to initiate the animation and state change

Comment: okay =) glad that's working for you. The swiping is the complicated part.

Comment: This is a pretty old question at this point so I don't honestly remember. There isn't actually any need for it in this scenario unless you wanted access to the "NetworkImage" object later on, which might be why I did that... or it could just have been a typo haha.